# Correct way to handle passing simple data into 'withObject' calls

Tags: objective-c

When using objective-c there are many different ways you can stumble across something that would uses withObject.  performSelectorOnMainThread is a good example.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(aSelector) withObject:anObject waitUntilDone:YES];
```

This calls the selector aSelector with the object anObject.  I often find myself with selector that takes a simple data type, like an int or an enum and I want to pass this off to a 'withObject'.  What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those kinds of operations, Cocoa really wants an Objective-C class that derives from NSObject.  To pass simple types like an integer, bool, or float value, the [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class can be used to encapsulate the value across selector call.  This is pretty easy with the utility methods the class provides to both create an NSNumber object from a primitive type, and retrieving that primitive type back from the object:

```
- (void)action:(id)sender
{
    enum EnumType eVal = /* ... */;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(aMethod:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)eVal] waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void)aMethod:(NSNumber)enumValue
{
    enum EnumType eVal = (EnumType)[enumValue intValue];
}
```

There is also the NSValue class that can do the same for lower-level types, like pointers or byte strings.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to wrap it in some sort of object. Either a custom data object or in the case of simple primitives, use `NSNumber`.

Comment: It's not so much that he'll *want* to but that he *has* to.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, well, this works too. I've seen this somewhere in ImageIO.  performSelector:@selector(setAllow:) withObject:(id)YES